# Effect size for binomial regression with weights in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, effect-size

I have the following setup in R and need to calculate an effect size:

```
Dependent = seq(0,1,length.out = 100)
Count = round(rnorm(n = 100,mean = 100,sd = 15))
Measure=1:100
dat = data.frame(Dependent=Dependent, Measure=Measure, Count=Count)
fit = glm(Dependent~Measure,dat,family = binomial(link="logit"), weights = Count)
```

Basically the "Dependent" variable is a proportion of how many 1 responses I got (each respondent provided 0 or 1), the "Count" variable contains the number of respondents per proportion in "Dependent".
The "Count" variable varies between the different proportions.
The measure variable is continuous.

What is the best estimate of effect size in this case?

Comment: Previous moderators (I'm not a moderator) would have suggested moving to Stack Overflow because they get programming answered very quickly, and it is more in line with their mission.  They might say it is off topic in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand your set up.   If dependent is the proportion, then you want `PositiveResponse = round(Count * Dependent)` and then something like `glm(cbind(PositiveResponse, Count - PositiveResponse) ~ Measure` (if you have a binomial glm you need so submit the dependent variable in the form of $(y, n-y)$ where $y$ is the number of positive trials, and $n$ is the number of trials.

That said, the effect size is the odds ratio.   The parameter estimate for Measure will the log odds of a positive response for a unit increase in Measure.   You can just take $\exp(\hat{\beta})$ to get the odds ratio. Admittedly odds ratios aren't the most user friendly effect size, but they tend to be well known within domain.